# Implement FIPS 140-2 with openssl

Tags: linux, openssl, fips

I want to use openssl with fips 140-2 to encrypt and decrypt files.

Source OS: ubuntu 18.04.
I have followed below steps:

1. I have uninstalled the existing openssl version.
2. Downloaded openssl-3.1.0.tar.gz, and compiled it with following commands (./configure,make, make install).
3. Now i have downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.16.tar.gz, and compiled with following commands (./configure,make, make install)
4. export OPENSSL_FIPS=/root/openssl-fips-2.0.16
5. executed the command from openssl-3.1.0 folder to enable openssl use fips module `./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl enable-fips` following make and make install.
6. Now if i execute followi command i am not seeing any fips version in `openssl version -a`,
   also `openssl rand -fips 32 > aes_key.bin` gives me rand: Unknown option: -fips
   this error.

Not sure if i am doing it correct.

Comment: The FIPS module you downloaded, openssl-fips-2.0.16, has *nothing* to do with OpenSSL 3.1.0, which has its own FIPS module included. The 2.0.16 module is for OpenSSL 1.0.2. I think you need to read the instructions on how to configure, build, and above all properly install, the openssl 3.1.0 libraries for enabling FIPS mode of operation.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have followed documentation, check out latest code. ./configure, make and make install => to install openssl. 
to enable support for fips ./config fips enable-fips, make, make install and then 
openssl fipsinstall -out   /usr/local/ssl/fipsmodule.cnf -module /usr/local/lib64/ossl-modules/fips.so
followed from this link. https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README-FIPS.md

Answer (score 1):

Followed below steps to install.

1. Downloaded openssl-3.1.0.tar.gz, and compile it with following commands (./configure,make,make test, make install)
2. To Enable  fips to used alongside with openssl use below commands (./config fips enable-fips,Make,Make install
   openssl fipsinstall -out   /usr/local/ssl/fipsmodule.cnf -module /usr/local/lib64/ossl-modules/fips.so)
3. couple of changes in openssl.conf mentioned as here [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/fips_module.html)